# Aurelia Keycloak integration

Tags: authentication, aurelia, keycloak

Very new to both Aurelia and keycloak and trying to get the two to work together. Using the Aurelia production seed without typescript

I am trying to follow this example that uses Angular2 [keycloak-angular2](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app)

*there is also an angular1 example in that repo*

Steps taken so far (I have updated the code snippet with additional progress)

1) Added the bower-jspm endpoint and installed keycloak.js

2) Added a keycloak-service.js (Updated)

````
```
import {keycloak} from 'keycloak';
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';

let logger = LogManager.getLogger('KeycloakService');

export class KeycloakService {
  static auth = {};

  static init() { 
    let keycloakAuth = new Keycloak({
      "realm": "my-realm",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
      "ssl-required": "external",
      "clientId": "CID"
    });

    KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
        .success(() => {
          logger.debug("Init Success");
          KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
          KeycloakService.auth.authz = keycloakAuth;
          KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl  + "/realms/my-realm/tokens/logout?redirect_uri=/";
          resolve(null);
        })
       .error(() => {
          logger.debug("Init Failed");
          reject(null)
       });
    });
   }

  logout(){
    logger.debug("Logging out");
    KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;
    KeycloakService.auth.authz = null;
    window.location.href = KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl;
  }

  getToken() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     if (KeycloakService.auth.authz.token) {
        logger.debug("Refreshing token");
        KeycloakService.auth.authz.updateToken(5)
          .success(function() {
            logger.debug("Token refreshed");
            resolve(KeycloakService.auth.authz.token);
          })
         .error(function() {
            logger.debug("Failed to refresh token");
            reject('Failed to refresh token');
         });
     }
   });
 }
}
```
````

3) In the main.js (Updated),

````
```
import {KeycloakService} from 'keycloak-service';
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();


  KeycloakService.init()
    .then(() => aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot()));
}
```
````

When i go to localhost:9000 , it redirects me to the login page, and allows me to login and takes me to the welcome page. Everytime i refresh the localhost:9000 page, it does not remember my previous login (even though my keycloak session is active) and forces me to login again. I am guessing this is due to onload login required. Though shouldnt it remember that i am already logged in?

After logging in, the console shows an error "keycloak.js:828 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null" on checkLoginIframe.

I am not sure how to implement the route/http interceptor

I tried creating a simple class to hit a health endpoint at the server

````
```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {KeycloakService} from 'keycloak-service';
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'fetch';

let logger = LogManager.getLogger('health');

@inject(HttpClient, KeycloakService)
export class Health {
  constructor(http, keycloakService) {
    http.configure(config => {
      config
      .useStandardConfiguration()
      .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:8081/api/health/')
      .withDefaults({
        headers: {
          'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
        }
      });
  });

    this.http = http;
    this.keycloakService = keycloakService;
  }

  activate() {
    return this.keycloakService.getToken().then(
      token => {
        // Somehow add this token to the header ...
        this.http.fetch('summary').then(response => response.json())
      }
    );
  }
}
````

```

However this fails with the same checkLoginIFrame issue again. Also unsure how i would inject the bearer token header at this point. Is there a better way to intercept this globally (or semi globally for certain routes) or should i create a superclass and extend all the services with it that need to send a token to the server.

I am trying to get to a point where the welcome screen is not secured, and possibly a search screen that is not secured, (so i wouldnt do onLoad: 'login-required'. I want to have a explicit link for login/signup on main page. And the rest of the navigation requires the user to be logged in

Has any one successfully achieved this and can share some code? As i said, primarily a server side dev with limited angular 1 experience and evaluating keycloak as well so pretty much uncharted waters with all this stuff

Oh and i couldnt just copy the keycloak.json from the keycloak console installation tab as is, had to change "resource" to "clientId" and "auth-server-url" to "url", is that normal behaviour?

---- UPDATE ----

so after debugging, the `document.body.appendChild(iframe);` does set the contentWindow on the iframe, but when the `checkLoginIframe` gets called after the interval expires, the contentWindow for some reason is changed to null. I guess it has something to do with when I do the init vs when aurelia is done doing its thing, i tried calling init at different points, but then the router gets in the way of things. Since i do not need to do load on init, i just do the init on configure in main.js and at least for now this issue goes away.

Using the js-console demo from keycloak as an example, i am trying to implement explicit login. The login button takes me to the keycloak login page, however on logging in, the issue i am running into now is that the aurelia router complains that `Error: Route not found: http://localhost:9000/?redirect_fragment=%2Fkcr#state=...&code=...' where kcr is the html/js route module i am using to put some buttons on the screen to test the functionality

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Initializing Keycloak with

```
keycloakAuth.init({onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false})
```

solved the problem for me.

The reason seems to be that the checkLoginIframe element is only correctly created and added to the dom if you configure `onLoad: 'check-sso'`. But that's only a guess informed by looking at and debugging through `keycloak.js`. If my guess is correct, `keycloak.js` should get some better configuration error handling.

Answer (score 0):

See [Aurelia-Keycloak](https://github.com/waynepennington/aurelia-keycloak).

## Aurelia-Keycloak

**Alpha version.**  An authentication plugin based on **KeyCloak**  for **Aurelia**  applications.

### Get Started

- Install Aurelia-Keycloak:

  jspm install aurelia-keycloak
- Add keycloak configuration and initialization settings:

Follow Keycloak directions for creating a keycloak.json configuration file.  Put this file in the same directory as your application's index.html file. Refer to the keycloak javascript adapter [documentation](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io) for its initialization options and API.

- Add plugin to your app's main.js. This example assumes your keycloak.json is in your root directory.  This code will immediately cause the login screen to appear.
  `.plugin('aurelia-keycloak', {initOptions:{ onLoad: 'login-required' }})`
- To defer login, use the following:
  `.plugin('aurelia-keycloak')`
  Then, construct a login button within your code to call the keycloak login function.
- Rather than use a keycloak.json file, you can insert the installation config with the plugin declaration

`.plugin('aurelia-keycloak',{install:{**PASTE GENERATED KEYCLOAK.JSON HERE**}},initOptions:{ onLoad: 'login-required' }}

**See the GITHUB for details.**

Comment: I installed the plugin and then copied the 'aurelia-keycloak.js' to ../jspm_packages/github/waynepennington/  and renamed it 'aurelia-keycloak@master.js'. However it cant find  `"http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/waynepennington/aurelia-keycloak@master/aurelia-keycloak.js. ` . So I tried changing this to `module.exports = require("github:waynepennington/aurelia-keycloak@master/aurelia-keycloak");` and put the "aurelia-keycloak,js" in the subdirectory its looking in. Then i get `aurelia-pal.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error invoking ViewSlot. Check the inner error for details.`

Comment: I'm looking into this now.  The problem may have to do with it being jspm'd as a "feature" verses a "plugin".  This causes Aurelia to look for an accompanying html file.  So one, either use a "noView" decorator so it doesn't look for the html. Or, just put a fake html file in like is done for the Aurelia Plugin Skeleton.  I'll try to resolve this today.

Comment: To speed things up, temporarily switching development to aurelia "feature" verses "plugin".  I'll provide you that code.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it. Also in case you did not get a chance to look at the update to my original post, do you have any ideas on the issue of route not found issue when keycloak redirects back to aurelia when doing explicit login rather than on load? Also thanks for pointing out the js-console example that helped a lot, I had missed that originally as i was only looking in the demo-templates subdirectory of their repo

Comment: At least got the redirect back to aurelia working, Had to change the responseMode for keycloak "init" from `fragment` to `query`. Need to dig into what the implications are of that, but atleast able to login successfully and back to the app. Still working on figuring out how to intercept and do refreshToken in a nice way as well as redirecting back to the last page accessed that prompted login rather than the root page.

Comment: Good.  My "feature" plugin is working for initialization.  However, the dependency injection is not.  'Still working it.

Comment: Did you end up disabling the iframe? That's what I ended up doing.  My plug in Aurelia-Keycloak is working and registered so that it is easier to use.  My code disables the iframe by default.    ... 'Will continue to tweek.

Comment: No, I did not disable iframe, not doing a load on init fixed the problem of ContentWindow being null on checkLoginIframe

Comment: @Omar A, Although I got the plug-in working without the iframe, I still need a solution that polls the token status.  My use-case requires access to the login and token status through the various views.  Manual token updates cause undesired side-effects.  So ...., I may add a timer and some pub-sub code.  Just as a note, I'm adding an easy REST endpoint config capability.  'Sounds like we're after similar goals.  Feel free to contact me at wayne.pennington@gmail.com.  What's your timezone?

Comment: timezone is sydney, Australia.  I am off the keycloak evaluation and onto other tasks. I think you are a lot further than where I got with what you are trying to achieve. I got it working just enough to test keycloak in a hacky way but decision is not to go with keycloak (nothing to do with aurelia). the init options i used ```initOptions = {
      responseMode: 'query',
      flow: 'standard',
      onLoad: 'check-sso'
    };```  my startup ordering is ```aurelia.start()
    .then(() => aurelia.setRoot())
    .then(() => KeycloakService.init());```